# How to kill a process in Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

In a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application I kill a process like this:

```
    Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("DataWedge");
    foreach (Process p in ps)
        p.Kill();
```

How can I do it in the [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) operating system?

(This sample doesn't work on Windows Mobile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate the Processes running on the device in order to get it's process ID. Once you've got the processId you can just do:

```
Process process Process.GetProcessById(processId);
process.Kill();
```

Here's an [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120121070906/http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/windows-cemobile-get-process-list-c) that deals with enumerating the processes, it also includes a kill example as well.

Comment: thank's for the help, but how i can know the processID that i need ?

Comment: You need to check the enumeration by the process name.

Comment: sorry about the ignorance...... how to do it ? can i get sample C# code for this ?

Comment: Look at the article I provided.

Comment: i try, but it dont work on windows mobile 2005 i get exceptionCode: 0x80000002  and   ExceptionAddress: 0x02e07084

Comment: 0x80000002 == OutOfMemeory.  Sounds like you probably have a recursion bug in your code.

Comment: Revived article link.

Answer (score 2):

Since the above article no longer exists I used the Wayback Machine to get the [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100202031003/http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/windows-cemobile-get-process-list-c) to use the code. Below is how you would use the code from the article to enumerate through the processes and kill the one that you want:

```
List<ProcEntry> processes = new List<ProcEntry>();
ProcessEnumerator.Enumerate(ref processes);

foreach (ProcEntry proc in processes)
{
    if (proc.ExeName == "DataWedge.exe")
    {
        ProcessEnumerator.KillProcess(proc.ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in this code that makes it always return an empty list.
First, add this constant :

```
private const uint TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS = 0x40000000;
```

Then call it like this :

```
IntPtr snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS, 0 );
```