# Symbol Device Kill Process

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, motorola-emdk

I'm trying to see how many instances of an application are running on a MC65 device, a Windows Mobile 6.5 device. Then if there is more than one instance of the application running kill all instances and run the application. I've tried that code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660087/how-to-kill-a-process-in-windows-mobile). But it doesn't work on the MC65 device. I believe this is because it is a symbol device and I've read somewhere that they act differently than non-symbol devices.

Does anyone know how to find out what processes are running on a symbol device programatically?

Update: Upon further testing the device is having problems creating a snapshot of the running processes. Still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a snapshot should work fine BUT you have to use a flag to avoid memory limitations throwing an exception:

```
    [Flags]
    private enum SnapshotFlags : uint
    {
        HeapList = 0x00000001,
        Process = 0x00000002,
        Thread = 0x00000004,
        Module = 0x00000008,
        Module32 = 0x00000010,
        Inherit = 0x80000000,
        All = 0x0000001F,
        NoHeaps = 0x40000000
    }
```

Then in a normal call to CreateToolhelp32Snapshot you can get a list of processes:

```
    public static Dictionary<UInt32, process> getProcessNameList()
    {
        int iCnt = 0;
        //List<processnames> name_list = new List<processnames>();
        Dictionary<UInt32, process> _pList = new Dictionary<uint, process>();
        uint procID = 0;
        IntPtr pHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.Process | SnapshotFlags.NoHeaps, procID);
        if ((Int32)pHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            throw new Exception("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());

        if ((int)pHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry = new PROCESSENTRY32();
            pEntry.dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(pEntry);
            if (Process32First(pHandle, ref pEntry) == 1)
            {
                do
                {
                    //name_list.Add(new processnames(pEntry.th32ProcessID, pEntry.szExeFile));
                    _pList[pEntry.th32ProcessID] = new process(pEntry.th32ProcessID, pEntry.szExeFile, new List<thread>());
                    iCnt++;
                } while (Process32Next(pHandle, ref pEntry) == 1);
            }
            else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Process32First error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
            CloseToolhelp32Snapshot(pHandle);
        }

        return _pList;
    }
```

The above code is part of my remote [ProcessorUsage test application](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/12/14/mobile-development-a-remote-cpu-monitor-and-cpu-usage-analysis/).

Nevertheless normal windows mobile application will terminate them self if a previous instance is already running. That is also the default when you create and run a SmartDevice project in CSharp or CPP targetting "Windows Mobile ...".
If you target a Standard Windows CE based SDK, there is no automatic code generated to prevent multiple instances in the start code of the app.

Let us know, if you still need assistance.

Comment: Thanks you. The NoHeap flag was exactly what I needed. Side note: although for the most part when I execute process.start only one instance will ever be ran. I have found if you time your calls right you can start multiple instances of a program.

Comment: Yes, the noHeap flag is essential since WM5/CE5. Timing should not enable to run an app with multiple instances. An app sould check at beginning if it is already running and then switch to previous instance and shutdown itself.

Comment: Then I don't know how it's happening but somehow multiple instances of one of my applications gets ran. Most of the time I only see one instance running, but occasionally I've seen two or three instances. Anyway, thanks again for the help it worked like a charm.